# Execute only when the previous function has completed inside a loop

Tags: javascript, synchronization

Here I want the function f2 to execute only after function f1 has completed.But my code does not wait for function f1 to complete.And also I want the loop to wait until and unless both f1 and f2 has completed.

```
{
    document.querySelector("input[name=username]").value  = "robert";

    var f1=function(k) 
    {  
        document.querySelector("input[name= password]").value  =k;
        document.getElementById("logincaption").click(); 

    }

    var f2=function()
    {
        b=document.getElementById("logincaption").getAttribute("value");
        window.alert(b);
    }

    for(k=1121;k<=1123;k++)
    {
        f1(k);
        f2();
    }    
}
```

Here is the code

```
<input type="text" maxlength="50" name="username">
<input type="password" autocomplete="off" name="password" maxlength="60">
<input type="submit" id="logincaption" value="Login" name="btnSubmit">`
```

Suppose if the password 1122  matches with the username the value changes from Login to Logout.I want to alert when it changes .

the click button calls the following function checkSubmit().

```
function checkSubmit()
{
    if(status!="LIVE")
        {
            document.frmHTTPClientLogin.mode.value=191;
            if(validateLogin())
                {UserValue=replaceAll(document.frmHTTPClientLogin.username.value,"'","''");queryString="mode=191&username="+encodeURIComponent(UserValue)+"&password="+encodeURIComponent(document.frmHTTPClientLogin.password.value)+"&a="+(new Date).getTime()+producttype;if(loginstate!=null){queryString+="&state="+loginstate}
            url="login.xml";
            makeAjaxRequest("POST",queryString,url,loginResponse)}
        }
        else
            {if
                (document.forms[0].btnSubmit.value==logoutValue)
                {document.frmHTTPClientLogin.mode.value=193;queryString="mode=193&username="+encodeURIComponent(document.frmHTTPClientLogin.username.value)+"&a="+(new Date).getTime()+producttype;url="logout.xml";
                makeAjaxRequest("POST",queryString,url,logoutResponse)}
            }return false}
```

Comment: By this code you provide there is no problem executing `f2` after `f1` because it seems to not have any async methods. What exactly the `f1` function does(I mean by the `click` triggered)?

Comment: Click triggers a login button with id logincaption and a default value="Login" and if the password and username are correct,the value changes to value="Logout".So i want my second function to alert logout if the username password matches.and if they do not match the value remains as Login.

Comment: So the click event starts an ajax request? If yes, you should call `f2` in its own callback. Otherwise it will be called before the request ends.

Comment: Supppose the password is 1122 so window.alert should display Login Logout Login but its displaying Login Login Login.

Comment: Yes its ajax request but what exactly do you mean by calling f2 in its own callback

Comment: Could you attach the code where you're setting the `logincaption`'s click event? (Or, specifically, where you're setting up the AJAX request)

Comment: on click the request is send .

Comment: Like @Bryce said, you should add your ajax script in the question, so we can help you. Otherwise, we can't do nothing but tell you to add your functions to the request callback.

Comment: How to get a ajax.scripr because i am using my code as a content script .i dont have a ajax script.....

Comment: @Bhuwan adding the portion of the code where you set the click event on `logincaption` would help

Comment: i have updated a the code.